# How can I change a label dynamically on a page, based on input from a text box?

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to create a more friendly input form where I ask for a user's name in a text box, and based on the information typed in, I would like to echo this to a display a little lower on the page, to personalize the page a little farther.

I'm trying to use AJAX, but am open to any better options out there...

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",document.getElementById("fname");,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<p>Contact's first name <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<div id="myDiv">Contact's</div> phone number <input type="text" id="phn"></p>
```

Comment: On every keyup you want to send a request?  Seems too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this simple code

```
<script>    
function myFunction(val){ 

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = val; 

}</script>
<p>Contact's first name <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction(this.value)">
<div id="myDiv">Contact's</div> phone number <input type="text" id="phn"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay let me get this properly.

1) User types his name

2) User has to submit the name (Add a button)

3) Using AJAX (Only if you have to store the name to DB dynamically, that's a good choice)

4) Update the user name if AJAX was success, or show a error

5) If you just want update name on page, no need for AJAX. (Well I don't see the use of it unless you are just trying to learn things)

**HTML**

```
<form id="user-form">
    <div>
        <span>Contact's first name</span>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Contact's phone number</span>
        <input type="text" id="phn" name="phn">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<p id="user-name">User name</p>
```

**JS**

```
var userForm = document.getElementById("user-form");
userForm.onSubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("user-id").innerHTML = name;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","file.ext",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("fname=" + name + "&phone=" + phone);
}
```

I would recommend you to start using jQuery library. It would simplify things a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for your ajax as it has some cross browser compatible functions such as `$.get`.

Apart from that I don't really see any other recommendation I could provide apart from a small syntax error:

`xmlhttp.open("GET",document.getElementById("fname");,true);`

You should remove the semi-colon:

`xmlhttp.open("GET",document.getElementById("fname"),true);`

As @Hitham commented, sending a request on every keyup is probably not wise. You should add a button and use the **click** event to send the information, or use a form and use the **submit** event. However, if this is a test exercise then it shouldn't be a problem.